# How do I get SUNW_1.4 version of libthread.so.1 for Solaris 2.6

Tags: patch-management, application, threads

I have installed an old application on an old Ultra 5 with Solaris 2.6.  When I start the app, I get the error: ld.so.1: : fatal : libthread.so.1: version 'SUNW_1.4' not found.  There is a version of libthread.so.1 present in /usr/lib dated sometime 1998.  This app is supposed to be compatible with Solaris 2.6, so I am not sure what is the problem.

My assumption is that I need a patch for this shared object.  Is this correct?  Will a patch update the version # so the app will run?  I have found a patch at http://sunsolve.sun.com/search/document.do?assetkey=1-21-105568-26-1, but it says that I need a service contract to download it.  Does it sound like the patch will solve my problem?  Does it make sense that this app is supposed to be compatible with Solaris 2.6 yet does not work?  Do I really need to pay money to Sun to get a patch for a ten year old operating system that I own legally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could well bet that 'SUNW_1.4' arrived in the patch that you have found. Your application might be for a certain release of Solaris 2.6. e.g. the one that shipped in 2001 rather than the one released in July 1997.

Solaris 2.6 is long [EOL](http://www.sun.com/service/eosl/eosl_solaris.html)

and is now on the graveyard section where no support is offered.

1. Check in your software cupboards to see if you have a newer version of 2.6 than that installed, see /etc/release to know what version it is.
2. Look through your old patchset CD's for later vintage 2.6
3. Older Solaris's CD sets are sometimes offered on E-Bay you might get lucky there.
4. Contact a Solaris hardware reseller and ask them for it, they might be able to help.
5. Contact Sun and pay for the patches.

Comment: Thanks davey, my /etc/release file says Solaris 2.6 5/98 s297s_hw3smccDesktop_09 SPARC.  I will check the disks in our lab to see if they are newer.  I have a patchset CD called Maintenence Update, I will look at this as well.  Cheers!

Comment: By looking at my /etc/release file and comparing to the documentation on the interwebs, I can see that I do not have the MU patchset installed.  I will try that next.